# How to produce repetitive HTML form fields?

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP to create a web application where user has to submit a form. Currently I am using simple html to render out the form just like given below.

```
<?php ?>
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post'>
    <div class='form-group mail-right-element'>
       <label class='col-sm-12 control-label mail-form-single-line-label' for='name 1'>Label 1</label>"
           <div class='col-sm-12'>
              <input name='name1' class='form-control validate' maxlength='100' placeholder='placeholder' value='value1'/>");
           </div>
    </div>
..
..
..// Some 20+ similar form fields
..
    <div class='form-group mail-right-element'>
       <label class='col-sm-12 control-label mail-form-single-line-label' for='name 20'>Label 20</label>"
           <div class='col-sm-12'>
              <input name='name20' class='form-control validate' maxlength='100' placeholder='placeholder' value='value20'/>");
           </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This looks really messy and hardly maintainable. So I went the php way as given below.

```
<?php
function GetFormRowHtml($label, $name, $maxlength, $placeholder, $value)
{
    return "<div class='form-group mail-right-element'>"
        . "<label class='col-sm-12 control-label mail-form-single-line-label' for='$name'>$label</label>"
        . "<div class='col-sm-12'>"
        . "<input name='$name' class='form-control validate' maxlength='$maxlength' placeholder='$placeholder' value='$value'/>"
        . "</div></div>";
}
?>


<form class='form-horizontal' method='post'>
    <?php
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label1', 'Name1', 'abc', 'abc');
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label2', 'Name2', 'abc', 'abc');
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label3', 'Name3', 'abc', 'abc');
    ?>
</form>
```

Is there any better approach to do this? I've read that having html in php is a really bad design. So should I go with the html way or continue using this approach? What are the disadvantages of using above method?

Comment: Without a framework like laravel or symfony? No, there isnt a better way then this one, which you have find out yourself.

Your way is realy clear, because you didnt repeat stuff that is equal. Maybe you can use another technique to replace (str_replace) instead of placing the $variable in the string.

Comment: how to implement str_replace()? Will there be any performance impact by using $variable within string?

Comment: Why is there 1 downvote? Please mention reason for downvoting :-)

Comment: I'll make an example for you, give me some minutes, ill post it as an answer. Not an performance impact, but if you have to sanitize, then this will end in a "bite into the desk" ;-)

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan install [twig](https://twig.symfony.com) from composer

Comment: @tereško I am new to php and web development. So I thought I should start with basics before getting into any frameworks

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan yes, and you should also have a solid understanding of OOP principles and practices, because some frameworks will otherwise teach you the wrong things :(

Comment: @tereško that's interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the input as a separate PHP file that you'd use for including:

**input-template.php**

```
<div class='form-group mail-right-element'>
   <label class='col-sm-12 control-label mail-form-single-line-label' for='<?= $name ?>'><?= $label ?></label>"
   <div class='col-sm-12'>
      <input id='<?= $name ?>' name='<?= $name ?>' class='form-control validate' maxlength='100' placeholder='<?= $placeholder ?>' value='<?= $value ?>'/>");
   </div>
</div>
```

And in your HTML:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post'>
    <?php
    $values = [ 
        [ "Label 1", "Name 1", "abc" , "abc" ],  
        [ "Label 2", "Name 2", "abc" , "abc" ],  
        [ "Label 3", "Name 3", "abc" , "abc" ],  
        [ "Label 4", "Name 4", "abc" , "abc" ]
     ];
     foreach ($values as $array) {       
        list($label,$name,$placeholder,$value) = $array;
        include "input-template.php"
     }
    ?>
</form>
```

The reason I personally Opt for this style is that IDEs generally can analyze the HTML in the template and help with formatting and detecting of errors while string HTML would usually not be treated that way.

Comment: I like this approach. But what if I've custom input like selectors, datepickers, file uploads in between normal text field? It's more like a complex form. Any way I like this approach :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do when looking at a common problem like this is to look at the some of the PHP frameworks and see how they handle it.

Looking at [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) or [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html) they abstract any inputs or labels into functions which generate the markup. So you're on the right track. The main issue with your code above is that you are combining layout with the label / field markup. Inherently this isn't' a massive issue but doesn't give your code much flexibility.

Markup should be moved into its own partial file so it's easy to maintain, form php functions should be more explicit generally.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that my code doesn't give me much flexibility. That's one reason why I asked out for help from here. I am a newbie in php and web. I'd really like to know the situation where I'll have some trouble. Thanks

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan if you're just starting out it may be worth getting into Laravel right away. It is a much steeper learning curve but it will be worth it longer term if you're planning to stick with PHP development.

Comment: @apokryfos I am almost done with the project. Getting into laravel right now seems to be impossible as I am closing in on the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach ...

```
function GetFormRowHtml($label, $name, $maxlength, $placeholder, $value)
{

    /**
     * @var array
     * Grouping all searches and replaces in one array
     */
    $sar = [
        '{label}' => $label,
        '{name}' => $name,
        '{maxlength}' => $maxlength,
        '{placeholder}' => $placeholder,
        '{value}' => $value
    ];


    /** 
     * @var $elementTemplate 
     * Template for a row
     */
    $elementTemplate =  "
        <div class='form-group mail-right-element'>
            <label class='col-sm-12 control-label mail-form-single-line-label' for='{name}'>{label}</label>
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <input name='{name}' class='form-control validate' maxlength='{maxlength}' placeholder='{placeholder}' value='{value}'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";

    return str_replace(array_keys($sar), array_values($sar), $elementTemplate);
}
?>


<form class='form-horizontal' method='post'>
    <?php
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label1', 'Name1', 'abc', 'abc');
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label2', 'Name2', 'abc', 'abc');
    echo GetFormRowHtml('Label3', 'Name3', 'abc', 'abc');
    ?>
</form>
```

The approach from apokryfos is another good solution.